# How to delete images cache in HTML (or JS)

Tags: javascript, html

i`m trying to develop web page using multiple different images but images are too many so occured web page crash.
i want to delete images with HTML(or JS) code

Without refesh(F5), Can i delete these images?

ps. i mean images generated at Developer (Tools->Resources->Frames->Images)

Comment: A crash occurring in a web browser's caching mechanism is not something you should be working around in Javascript.  Instead, report it to the browser vendor so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images listed there (Tools->Resources->Frames->Images) are the images that were required while loading the page.

There's no way of deleting these items unless you modify the page and remove them from the source

Comment: Can i delete image from source? when i declare this code

var image = new Image();
image.src = buffer[seekBar.value];
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); 

image is generated

Comment: The image has been loaded and is cached locally. Because JavaScript only runs after the image has been loaded, I don't think this will have the desired effect.

Comment: @user3867698 you could try merging the images into one and using a sprite approach.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try to remove the images from page like this..

```
$("img").attr("src","")
```

you can call this on button click or any event you want this will clear all the image from your page..

Thanks